# What animal did the makers base the Razorwhip on?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

HTTYD dragons seem to be based on animals in real life (for example, Snotlout's Hookfang is based on a tiger). **What animal is the Razorwhip based on in real life?**

I want to draw the characters as 'real life people and their pets' but I'm struggling to work out how to draw the Razorwhip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rhino

Just by the horn alone and the fact that it is a silver/grey colour I would say that it is almost certainly largely based on a rhino.

[image: Heather flying on Windshear]

[image: Rhino]